# Cmakelist For Jetson GPIO on ROS melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to use GPIO on Jetson via ROS but seems like my CMakelist is not properly setup due to which I am getting errors as

```
undefined reference to 'GPIO::setmode(GPIO::NumberingModes)'
```

Below is my Cmakelist

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(camera_gpio)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package(
  LIBRARIES camera_gpio
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs)
# set(GPIO_INCLUDE_DIR ../include )

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(gpio_control src/camera_gpio_node.cpp)
target_link_libraries(gpio_control ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(gpio_control ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my file structure

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/387144/cmakelist-for-jetson-gpio-on-ros-melodic/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2021-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had used the Python version for jetsonGPIO communication due to which I didn't have to worry about the CMakelist. Just incase anyone comes across the same issue.

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2021-09-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0